# Editing nsswitch.conf to check for files other than /etc/passwd while searching local files for user details

Tags: password, nsswitch, radius

I have a file in `/etc` named `radius` which contains the user account details similar to `/etc/passwd` but of Radius users. How do I configure `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to check `/etc/radius` in addition to checking `/etc/passwd` when searching for local files?
For example
I have a  line in my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` which says

```
passwd:     files nis
```

`files` here searches only in `/etc/passwd`. How do I make it search other files?

Comment: you can't use nsswitch.conf to remplqce /etc/passwd. this file is intented to switch between localfile, nis or dns. if /etc/radius is similar to passwd, just do a `cat /etc/radius >> /etc/passwd`

Comment: I don't want the entries to be in /etc/passwd. I dont want to replace /etc/passwd but I want this file to be searched too in addition to /etc/passwd

Comment: can you give a sample of /etc/radius ?

Comment: test::161:100:Test User:/:/bin/bash
I have added a test user in radius server in users file like
test  Cleartext-Password:"test"

Comment: this look like /etc/passwd entry, you have to merge with /etc/passwd. I don't think of any switch in nsswitch.conf that will "add" /etc/radius to /etc/passwd.

Comment: you could clone the nss_files library and make the cloned one search `/etc/radius` (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204350/)